# Sizing Bootstrap tooltip for image

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I am trying to adapt Bootstrap 4 tooltip to display images.

```
<img src="myimage.png" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title=\'<img src="myimage.png" class="d-block">\'>
```

In order to do it I had to add a custom CSS to allow tooltip scale to the width of the image.

```
.tooltip-inner {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.tooltip.show {
    opacity: 1;
}
.tooltip img {
    margin: 5px 0;
    background-color: #333;
}
```

It works great, however all my regular text tooltips also scale. I would like the text tooltips act as they were. I tried adding class to my code but the issue is actually in the tooltip code that is generated on hover. Is there a way to use my custom CSS only for images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that tooltip's `template` [option](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/#options) could help you to do what you want.

For example, you could create a specific template only for your image, using a specific class to format only its tooltip.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();  

  $('[data-toggle="tooltip-image"]').tooltip({
    template:'<div class="tooltip" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner image"></div></div>'
  });    
});
```

```css
.tooltip-inner.image {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.tooltip.show {
    opacity: 1;
}
.tooltip img {
    margin: 5px 0;
    background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
  <p><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Normal tooltip very very long => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec facilisis vehicula diam ac ornare. Vestibulum consequat, quam vitae porta ornare, nibh leo convallis ipsum, vel interdum est ex nec urna. Nunc cursus semper nunc, sit amet viverra quam placerat vitae. Etiam vitae pharetra erat. Integer lobortis enim non nisl hendrerit sodales. Ut interdum luctus tristique. Nullam vestibulum tincidunt ultricies. Etiam ut nunc lectus. Aliquam fermentum magna a arcu finibus sodales. Sed a eros ex. Pellentesque dictum finibus augue nec sagittis. ">Hover over me</a></p>
  <p><img src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" data-toggle="tooltip-image" data-html="true" title='<img src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" class="d-block">'></p>
</div>
```